# Haskell: Detect current OS

Tags: haskell

I'm currently writing a Haskell package. I want it to behave differently on Windows and Unix. What is the most "correct" way to detect what OS my code is being compiled on?

I did try using CPP and `#ifdef _WIN32`, but that doesn't appear to work at all.

Is there another macro? Can I get Cabal to tell me? Do I need to try something else entirely?

Comment: `#ifdef mingw32_HOST_OS`.

Comment: It would be great if someone could explain the difference between `#if defined(_WIN32)` and `#if defined(mingw32_HOST_OS)`. E.g. in `base` it is a mix of both and it is not clear why.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting the [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros):

> The symbols defined by GHC are listed below.
>
> [...]
>
> `os_HOST_OS=1` - This define allows conditional compilation based on the Operating System, where `os` is the name of the current Operating System (eg. `linux`, `mingw32` for Windows, `solaris`, etc.).

So to detect whether your code is being compiled on Windows you should use

```
#ifdef mingw32_HOST_OS
```

Obviously, you need to have CPP enabled for that to work.

For those who are wondering - `mingw32_HOST_OS` is also defined on 64-bit Windows:

```
C:\ghc-7.8.2\bin>ghc --info
...
,("Build platform","x86_64-unknown-mingw32")
,("Host platform","x86_64-unknown-mingw32")
,("Target platform","x86_64-unknown-mingw32")
...

C:\ghc-7.8.2\bin>ghc -E -optP-dM -cpp foo.hs

C:\ghc-7.8.2\bin>cat foo.hspp
{-# LINE 1 "foo.hs" #-}
#define __ASSEMBLER__ 1
#define mingw32_HOST_OS 1    
#define __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ 708    
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1    
#define TABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE 1    
#define x86_64_HOST_ARCH 1    
#define x86_64_BUILD_ARCH 1    
#define mingw32_BUILD_OS 1    
#define __SSE2__ 1    
#define __SSE__ 1
```

Confusingly, `mingw64_HOST_OS` is not - use `x86_64_HOST_ARCH` to detect 64-bit Windows specifically.

Comment: I like this because it lets me choose what to do, but with no runtime overhead. It's a bit sad it's specific to MinGW though...

Comment: What do you mean by "specific to MinGW"? As the manual says, you can also use `linux_HOST_OS`, `solaris_HOST_OS`, etc.

Answer (score 40):

You could use `System.Info` as defined in the base package [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/System-Info.html):

```
> :m + System.Info
> os
"darwin"
> arch
"i386"
```

Comment: I like this because it's just plain ordinary Haskell code looking at a plain ordinary constant. Nice!

Comment: Fantastic! I'm always in favour of solutions not involving direct use of `CPP` ;)

Comment: I am very surprised that all the answers, all the people derived to using some Cabal CPP plugins or Cabal modules, to determine the platform, when from 2001 (at the very least) in the `base` there is `System.Info`. And there is `System.Environment` to determine the OS from environment. And there is `posix` package that adds another bunch of options.

Answer (score 6):

Cabal's Distribution.System module has an [OS data type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.4.1.0/docs/Distribution-System.html#t:OS) and an [Arch data type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.4.1.0/docs/Distribution-System.html#t:Arch), so you can pattern-match against named constructors instead of stringy data.

For example, you can use [`buildOS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.4.1.0/docs/Distribution-System.html#v:buildOS):

```
case buildOS of
  Windows -> -- do something
  _ -> -- do something else
```

Comment: This answer could benefit so much from an example of usage.

Answer (score 5):

These are all good answers. For completeness, it seems Cabal also has a hook for this:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/Cabal/authors.html#conditions

In particular, it's slightly sad that "Windows" is identified as "mingw32". I hate to think what would happen if I went and installed the 64-bit GHC! (Would that then be "mingw64"?) And what if one day GHC is built with some other compiler? Or, dare we dream, there exist Haskell compilers that aren't GHC? (OK, that sounds fairly far-fetched right now, but it could plausibly happen...)

It seems that Cabal has special-case logic to deal with this, such that `os(windows)` is supposed to work all the time. It seems to me that by getting Cabal to do the work, if Wild Things happen in the future, it will be Cabal's job to sort that out, not mine.

Comment: `mingw32_HOST_OS` is also defined on 64-bit Windows. See my updated answer.