# Conditional compilation for macOS

Tags: macos, haskell, preprocessor

Using `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}`, is there a preprocessor define I can `#ifdef` to check whether current compilation is for macOS?

I tried `__APPLE__` and others as well as googling for answers but couldn't find it.

Comment: I know you can write _in the cabal_ file `os(windows)` for example, and use it as a flag. This is what [ghcup](https://github.com/haskell/ghcup-hs/blob/master/ghcup.cabal) does. I don't know how to do it directly on the Haskell file

Comment: This reminds me that I have an ongoing action item to actually look into `floskell` tooling ....

Comment: If at all possible, you should really try to avoid such conditionals in your code - but instead put them into _cabal

Comment: @MartinBaulig: for reference this is what I'm doing https://github.com/lamdu/momentu/compare/macos-opengl-lock

In the cabal / package.yaml I think I would need to specify additional conditional source directories for this? Wouldn't it be a lot more involved? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition appears to be `darwin_HOST_OS`! (found it by guessing based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23183999/40916) to a similar question)